# Openstack installation using devstack - liberty

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am getting error while installing the openstack-liberty using devstack  in
"Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
Installation log is in http://pastebin.com/ULhXbC8u
Trying to install the liberty version.

```
stack@jan27:/tmp$  git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
stack@jan27:/tmp/devstack$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/stable/kilo
  remotes/origin/stable/liberty
  remotes/origin/stable/mitaka
  remotes/origin/stable/newton
stack@jan27:/tmp/devstack$ git checkout stable/liberty
stack@jan27:/tmp/devstack$ git branch -a
  master
* stable/liberty
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/stable/kilo
  remotes/origin/stable/liberty
  remotes/origin/stable/mitaka
  remotes/origin/stable/newton
```

Thanks & Regards,
Binoy M V

Answer (score 0):

try upgrade pip use `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I have done that. and updated to the newer version. But when i run the script again it will uninstall the pip and again install the same version. So next time also i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounter the same problem. Resolve it by :

> Change the pip value to the latest version, in **~/devstack/tools/cap-pip.txt**

*Example of cap-pip.txt content* : pip==18